# Why can't we sum two $n\times m$ and $u \times v$ matricies for all positive integer $n,m,u,v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why does the sum$$\left[\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&-1\\2 &3\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\0&-1 &1 &7\end{matrix}\right]$$ undefined? Let's expand these matricies for  $x,y,z,t$ and sum $$\left[\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&-1\\2 &3\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\0&-1 &1 &7\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\2 &3&0&0\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\0&-1 &1 &7\\0&0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$$$=\left[\begin{matrix}2&4&3&4\\0&-2&1 &7\\2&3&0&0\end{matrix}\right].$$

We had some equations which assumed correct, then we have new equations which are still correct. So why can't we define like this and why do we prefer to say undefined?

For well-define part: expansion is just for left and down.

Comment: Because of convention.

Comment: Let's make a new convention. Why don't we make? (I don't want this but...).

Comment: Then justify it. How is it useful?

Comment: @studentforever one reason **not** to adopt this definition is that we lose the property
$$
A - B = 0_{m \times n} \implies A = B
$$

Comment: I explained as coefficient matrices and this is well-defined if we put how we have to do.  So does it need to be useful?

Comment: You add 2 columns of zeros to the $3\times 2$ matrix. Why are these two columns to the right of the original? Why not to the left? Why not one on each side? Likewise, the zero row you add to the $2\times 4$ matrix. Why is it in the bottom, why not top? So I think you need (a) be more explicit and consistent in your construction (b) show why it is interesting. And then perhaps people can invest their time in your construction.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, We won't lose this property. If we restrict zero rows.

Comment: @studentforever what do you mean by "restricting zero rows"?  Do you mean that we simply don't allow matrices with zero-rows?

Comment: We can just for rank part. But I didn't define any rank or nullity here. I am just talking for coefficient matrices.  If everything is okay, why cant I define as?

Comment: We lose a lot of nice properties with the sum defined this way, $(A+B)-B$ might have a different size from $A+(B-B)$, $(A+B)C$ might be defined while $AB+BC$ might not and so on

Comment: @studentforever there's nothing stopping you from using your definition, especially if you're just considering matrices as objects to be added together.  That being said, it is useful to be able to consider the rank and nullity of these "coefficient matrices", so this use is limited.

Comment: @studentforever, you can define whatever you want, but you shouldn't expect others to find your definition useful or interesting in any way. So far all you did was to give one way to expand both matrices so they have the same format, but you didn't give any motivation as to why you expand the first matrix only to the right, you didn't give any example of where this would be useful, you didn't clarify what you mean by restricting zero rows...so yes, that is a definition, now what? Please make us interested in your definition.

Comment: @Hirshy, I am not saying it is useful and I am not saying 'come on, let's use definition'. I am just asking why do we prefer the other? I am just saying this extension simply gives new correct equations.

Comment: And I'm saying: yes, this is something we don't do for reasons already mentioned in the comments By Omnomnomnom and Alessandro . So it is now your turn to justify your claim as why we should consider working with this definition. As for your argument it gives us new correct equations: let's define a new multiplication on $\mathbb R$ via $$\odot:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R,(x,y)\mapsto x\odot y:=0.$$ This will give us lots of new correct equations, e.q. $1\odot 2=2\odot 3=-4\odot\sqrt{2}=e\cdot\pi$, but for obvious reasons we do not use this kind of multiplication.

Comment: @Hirshy, Is there any reason to add two coefficient matrices of two $n \times m$? I have same reason.

Comment: @Alessandro, they will have same size. If we ignore always last zero columns and rows.

Comment: Yes, for the (usual) sum of two $n\times m$ matrices there are lots of applications. The easiest that comes to mind would be to consider two linear mappings $\varphi,\psi:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$. After chosing bases we can find matrices $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ with $\varphi(x)=Ax,\psi(x)=Bx$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^m$. If we now look at the sum of these functions $\varphi+\psi:\mathbb R^m\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ we get that $(\varphi+\psi)(x)=(A+B)x$.

Comment: If I ignore the 0 rows does a $4\times5$ matrix with the last 2 rows filled zeros represent a transformation $\mathbb{K}^5\to\mathbb{K}^4$ or a transformation $\mathbb{K}^5\to\mathbb{K}^2$?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that there is not a truly "natural" way to embed the two matrices in a larger parent vector space containing both.

This is analogous to the problem of computing the sum of a scalar and a vector, such as $$3 + (0,2)$$
You may want to think of this as $(3,0)+(0,2)=(3,2)$, but why not $(0,3)+(0,2)=(0,5)$? Or even $(0,0,0,3)+(0,2,0,0)=(0,2,0,3)$?

Comment: I actually defined as well defined. I told how we could. So $3+(0,2)=(3,2)$. But we can put right and down. Then it will be $(0,5)$. 

But in second situation coefficient matrices need to be $(0,3)$ not $3$.